# Evaluating the norm of an ideal by considering integral basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

There is this trick in my lecture notes that I don't think is correct. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ then my notes say that the ideal $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ has obviously norm $2$ since $1,1+\sqrt{-5}$ forms an integral basis for $O_K$ I don't see how those are related. For example using the logic above $1,\sqrt{-5}$ also forms an integral basis for $O_K$ however $(2,\sqrt{-5})$ has not norm 2 since $1\in (2,\sqrt{-5})$. So  this argument with the integral basis doesen't work in that case. Can anyone explain me what my notes mean?

I have also seen for example $(3, 2 + \sqrt{
−5}), (7, 3 + \sqrt
{−5})$ have norms $3$ and $7$ respectively. Again with justification than $1,1+\sqrt{-5}$ forms an integral basis. So can anyone please explain what is the logic behind this argument and when does this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Replace "norm $2$" with "norm dividing $2$". The argument is that the $\mathbb Z$-module homomorphism $\mathcal O_K\to \mathbb Z/2$, $a+b\alpha\mapsto a\pmod 2$ has kernel $(2,\alpha)$, but this map need not be surjective.